# java Jersey Facebook Graph API unsubscribe page app is not installed error

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

When I try to subscribe page from app the following way:

```
client.target("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/" + pageId + "/subscribed_apps")
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity
                            .entity("{\"access_token\":\"" + oauthCode + "\"}",
                                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
```

I get error: #100 App is not installed

What does it mean? What should I do to subscribe and unsubscribe pages? What the difference between app installation and subscription?

Comment: I use page token that was obtained from /subscriptions Also, this endpoint accept json, why not? Thanks

Comment: Because it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. If FB page is not connected to the app, it gives 'App is not installed'. Otherwise it says 'success:true'. So please ignore this exception if you try to unsubscribe from not subscribed page, or check the status first.